# Libgdx camera.zoom is not zooming for me

Tags: android, libgdx

I am creating a game using libgdx for android.  On my highscore screen when the user clicks the textfield to enter their name the onscreen keyboard appears and just covers the textfield so the user can not see what they are typing.  To counter this I am trying to zoom my camera in to the textfield but when I use the zoom feature nothing happens and I don't understand why.  Can anyone please point me in the right direction.  Thanks. Below I am trying to zoom in when the textfield is clicked.

```
 textscore.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            public void clicked(InputEvent e, float x, float y) {

                camera.zoom =2; //zoom in

             textscore.getOnscreenKeyboard();
             stage.setKeyboardFocus(textscore);
            }
        });

//in show
camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
camera.setToOrtho(false, W,H);

    stage.addActor(textscore);
    textscore.setVisible(true);
     textscore.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            public void clicked(InputEvent e, float x, float y) {
                System.out.println("focused");
                camera.zoom -= 2;

             //textscore.getOnscreenKeyboard();
             //stage.setKeyboardFocus(textscore);
            }
        });
```

In render

camera.update();

Answer (score 4):

first thing is better use

```
    camera.zoom += 2; //zooming out
    camera.zoom -= 2; //zooming in
```

secondly you've probably forgotten about

```
    camera.update();
```

after setting its new zoom

Comment: Thanks.  yes I have tried camera.update(); and camera.zoom-=2; before but still nothing

Comment: Try to add camera.update() into your render method. Also attach the code of the Screen please

Comment: I tested the camera.zoom in the render method and it appears to work because the touch distance is off by about twice as much but the actual images are the same its not zooming into the textfield.  I will upload the camera bits because theres a lot of other code.

Comment: Would I need to create a viewport and add that over the textfield so to speak to make that area fill the screen?

Comment: I have now added in spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined); to the render method and it appears to be zooming out each time I click the textfield.  However I can't get it to zoom in whether I do  camera.zoom += 2 or  camera.zoom -= 2.

Comment: -=2 just appears to flip it for some reason and zoom out.  whereas +=2 just zooms out.

Comment: Ok Now -=0.02 seems to get it to zoom in as planned but the buttons and textfield remains the same size, so just need to solve that now.

Comment: when camera.zoom value starts to became negative the effect is like you are describing :) try with lesser value for example -= 0.2f - also if you want to set "camera view width" you should check if `this.camera.frustum.planePoints[1].x - this.camera.frustum.planePoints[0].x; == yourWidth` - you can decrease step by step until width above is > that your textfield width + remember to set camera position at center of textfield